# how can I sort through an ☺how can i compare two arrays and log same or different values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I´m trying to loop through an array and compare each value with the values of a different array.
Every value that is not in the second array I want to console.log them in a third array.
How can I do that I tried so many things and looked up tips and examples on the internet but nothing works for me.
Following is the task: *Console log all fruits from `fruitsToCheck` which are not included in the array `fruitsWeHave`.

1. Split all fruits in `fruitsToCheck` with the symbol `,`. ==> done
2. Check for all fruits in the resulting array if they are included in `fruitsWeHave`.*

Following is the code.

```js
let fruitsWeHave = ["Bananas", "Apples", "Pineapples", "Watermelons", "Mangos"];

 let fruitsToCheck = "Mangos,Kiwis,Oranges,Watermelons,Coconuts,Papayas,Grapes";

 // TODO: Console log all fruits from fruitsToCheck which are not included in
 // the array fruitsWeHave
let splitFruitsToCheck = fruitsToCheck.split(',')

console.log(splitFruitsToCheck);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What have you tried? Add that code to the question as a [mcve]. You'll want to maybe look at [loops/iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), maybe [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)...

Comment: He just wants to console log any fruit from `fruitsToCheck` if they aren't in the `fruitsWeHave`. Sorry but did you even read the question or did you just post some copy pasted comment and saw array and thought maybe filter? Come on...

Comment: I tried using a for loop to compare each index of the fruitsToCheck with each index of the fruitsWeHave. My idea was to let the loop run through each index of fruitsToCheck and compare them, if it wasn´t in fruitsToHave push into a new array and after it checked everything I would console.log the new array

Comment: @LeonMichalak every question should contain an attempt to resolve the problem. StackOverflow is not meant to be a code-writing service

Comment: I know what the OP wants @LeonMichalak but we ask people if they've made an attempt because we like to see that they've worked on a solution before asking a question. Note that your answer doesn't address the "third array" which `filter` would provide. Maybe don't be so quick to rush to judgement.

Comment: @NicoHaase the problem he's solving is less than 10 lines of code... come on. He stated (maybe not as in-depth as you'd like) what he tried/his thoughts on tackling the problem. I'm assuming he's a beginner and got stuck with something and is lost. Costs nothing to just help with something small (to us).

Comment: @Andy No i get you but for a small problem like this, I'd rather just help with what is clearly stated, and that might be enough of a push for him to figure the rest out :)

Comment: I appreciate every help tips code examples to look at.
If something is missing in my question just let me know or if more information is needed. I just started with the It Bootcamp and sometimes it is kinda overwhelming to new so many different things all at once and I start to overlook little things or forget things I already learned. 
Like I said I welcome every help.

Answer (score 1):

*"I tried using a for loop to compare each index of the `fruitsToCheck` with each index of the `fruitsWeHave`. My idea was to let the loop run through each index of `fruitsToCheck` and compare them, if it wasn´t in `fruitsToHave` push into a new array and after it checked everything I would `console.log` the new array."*

Based on this comment you have all the component for solving this. So here are a few variations.

1. Basic [`for loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement), and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
const fruitsWeHave = ['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Pineapples', 'Watermelons', 'Mangos'];
const fruitsToCheck = 'Mangos,Kiwis,Oranges,Watermelons,Coconuts,Papayas,Grapes';
const splitFruitsToCheck = fruitsToCheck.split(',');

// Declare a new array
const unavailableFruit = [];

// Iterate over `splitFruitsToCheck` and if the current
// fruit is not in `fruitsWeHave` (indexOf is -1)
// push it into `unavailableFruit`
for (let i = 0; i < splitFruitsToCheck.length; i++) {
  const fruit = splitFruitsToCheck[i];
  if (fruitsWeHave.indexOf(fruit) < 0) {
    unavailableFruit.push(fruit);
  }
}

// Log unavailable fruit
console.log(unavailableFruit);
```

2. [`for/of loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement), and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const fruitsWeHave = ['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Pineapples', 'Watermelons', 'Mangos'];
const fruitsToCheck = 'Mangos,Kiwis,Oranges,Watermelons,Coconuts,Papayas,Grapes';
const splitFruitsToCheck = fruitsToCheck.split(',');

// Declare a new array
const unavailableFruit = [];

// Iterate over `splitFruitsToCheck` and if the current
// fruit is not in `fruitsWeHave` push it into `unavailableFruit`
for (const fruit of splitFruitsToCheck) {
  if (!fruitsWeHave.includes(fruit)) {
    unavailableFruit.push(fruit);
  }
}

// Log unavailable fruit
console.log(unavailableFruit);
```

3. Using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) - `filter` returns a new array of elements that fulfil the condition in its callback:

```js
const fruitsWeHave = ['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Pineapples', 'Watermelons', 'Mangos'];
const fruitsToCheck = 'Mangos,Kiwis,Oranges,Watermelons,Coconuts,Papayas,Grapes';
const splitFruitsToCheck = fruitsToCheck.split(',');

// We don't have to declare a separate third array because
// `filter` itself returns an array
const unavailableFruit = splitFruitsToCheck.filter(fruit => {
  return !fruitsWeHave.includes(fruit);
});

console.log(unavailableFruit);
```

Comment: includes() is not supported in Internet Explorer or Edge 13 (and earlier versions).
Personally I don't care. I've Safari, Opera, Chrome Firefox and Tor.
So upvote anyway.

Comment: IE reached EOL in June and only has 0.28% market share (MDN removed it from all their compatibility lists too), and Edge 13 is over seven years old. No-one is developing for browsers that old. @tatactic

Comment: You're right! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (const fruit of splitFruitsToCheck) {
  if (!fruitsWeHave.includes(fruit)) {
    console.log(fruit);
  }
}
```

You were correct to start of with splitting the `fruitsToCheck` array!

Basically, you need to go through each fruit to check, and if `fruitsWeHave` doesn't have that fruit, then you can do your console log.

If you want me to explain anything let me know :)

Comment: I would love if you could explain me your code because itś the first time I see the let variableName of variableName2

Comment: Sure. Same thing as doing
`for (let i = 0; i < splitFruitsToCheck.length; i++) {}`, they both achieve the same goal however the `const x of y` is IMO better for when you don't care about the index of the item in the array, just the time itself!

Comment: thanks I also now see my mistake, you helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to find the fruits which not present in fruitsWeHave array

```js
const fruitsWeHave = ["Bananas", "Apples", "Pineapples", "Watermelons", "Mangos"];
    const fruitsToCheck = "Mangos,Kiwis,Oranges,Watermelons,Coconuts,Papayas,Grapes";
    const checkList = fruitsToCheck.split(',');

    const fruitsMap = new Map(); 

// setting all the fruits in fruitsWeHave to Map object
    for(const fruit of fruitsWeHave) {
       fruitsMap.set(fruit, true);
    }

    for(const fruit of checkList) {
// access fruit name in constant time O(1)
      if(!fruitsMap.has(fruit)) { // checking whether fruit presents or not 
         console.log(fruit);
      }
    }
```